# Natbib giving single character instead of author-year

Tags: natbib

I am using MiKTeX 2.9/TeXmaker. When I cite(`\citep{}`) with the `natbib` package, I get random characters e.g [a],[x] etc, instead of e.g [John1998]. I ran `PdfLatex->Bibtex->Pdflatex->Pdflatex`, but still getting the same result. I am writing my first document in LaTeX and its my thesis, so please forgive if I overlooked any minor error or method.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Photonic crystals are a class of materials 
that are either man made\citep{Yablonovitch1993} or 
naturally found\citep{Zi2003} 
.
.
.
.
.
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Output:

> Photonic crystals are a class of materials that are either man made[b,
>   a] or naturally found [e, i].

Within BibTeX file

```
@ARTICLE{Yablonovitch1993,
  author = {Yablonovitch, E.},
  title = {Photonic band-gap structures},
  journal = {J. Opt. Soc. Am. B},
  year = {1993},
  volume = {10},
  pages = {283-295},
  number = {2}
}

@ARTICLE{Zi2003,
  author = {Zi, Jian and Yu, Xindi and Li, Yizhou and Hu, Xinhua and Xu, Chun
    and Wang, Xingjun and Liu, Xiaohan and Fu, Rongtang},
  title = {Coloration strategies in peacock feathers},
  journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {100},
  pages = {12576-12578},
  number = {22},
  abstract = {We report the mechanism of color production in peacock feathers. We
    find that the cortex in differently colored barbules, which contains
    a 2D photonic-crystal structure, is responsible for coloration. Simulations
    reveal that the photonic-crystal structure possesses a partial photonic
    bandgap along the direction normal to the cortex surface, for frequencies
    within which light is strongly reflected. Coloration strategies in
    peacock feathers are very ingenious and simple: controlling the lattice
    constant and the number of periods in the photonic-crystal structure.
    Varying the lattice constant produces diversified colors. The reduction
    of the number of periods brings additional colors, causing mixed
    coloration.}
}
```

.bbl file contents (Only the above two references are shown. I deleted the references from other parts of my document for convenience):

```
\begin{thebibliography}{29}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Yablonovitch(1993)]{Yablonovitch1993}
E.~Yablonovitch.
\newblock Photonic band-gap structures.
\newblock \emph{J. Opt. Soc. Am. B}, 10\penalty0 (2):\penalty0 283--295, 1993.

\bibitem[Zi et~al.(2003)Zi, Yu, Li, Hu, Xu, Wang, Liu, and Fu]{Zi2003}
Jian Zi, Xindi Yu, Yizhou Li, Xinhua Hu, Chun Xu, Xingjun Wang, Xiaohan Liu,
  and Rongtang Fu.
\newblock Coloration strategies in peacock feathers.
\newblock \emph{Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences}, 100\penalty0
  (22):\penalty0 12576--12578, 2003.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you give an example of an entry in the `references.bib` file?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I use endnote for managing references and then later imported them to Jabref, then used automatic key generation of jabref before exporting the library as references.bib

Comment: Can you add the contents of the `.bbl` file you get when running BibTeX on the minimal example above?

Comment: I see nothing strange: the `bbl` file is just the same as the one I get. Are you sure you have no `\setcitestyle` or `\citestyle` command in your document? Does running the example present the same problem?

Comment: No, I dont have these commands anywhere.

Comment: You wrote " I deleted the references from other parts of my document for convenience):". This indicates that you didn't test the minimal example but some larger document. Do you get the same result if you really run the minimal example?

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer that helps! I now get proper citations..But I don't know why it doesn't when I have it with the other references.

Comment: Well create a minimal example - that is *not* an arbitrary small example, but a small example that *demonstrates* the problem. So start with your problematic document and strip it down.

Comment: Thanks again @egreg and Ulrike. I am assuming there is some other problem when it comes to the entire code and not just MWE,  which I will try correcting or post as a separate question.

Comment: @paisawallah Why a separate question? Try minimizing your preamble so that the code still shows the problem and put the code so obtained in the present question.

Comment: @egreg - the solution was to remove \usepackage{newclude}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks for your input. I took the trouble in removing each and every part of code and checking the output. the problem was the usage of newclude

Answer (score 2):

I carefully sifted through the code, removing bits and pieces and checked for the output. It seems `\usepackage{newclude}` was the culprit. Without `newclude`, the citation is displayed perfectly as desired i.e. Author-year.